# Trying to install Perl module (Math::Random) and unable to find pathway use/bin/make which does not exist

Tags: perl, math, random

Trying to install Math::Random using sudo cpan

```
Writing Makefile for Math::Random
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for G/GR/GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz
  GROMMEL/Math-Random-0.72.tar.gz
  /use/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

The path /use/... does not exist, and make is located in usr/bin/make
Have tried reinstalling cpan, perl via brew, and reinstalling make
I'm using perl v5.34.0

Has anyone got any suggestions of what else I could try? Any thoughts much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Does 'perl -V | grep /use' give any output? (Make sure you use the same perl that you're trying to install with.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion. I don't get any output with that, despite reinstalling perl

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what Linux version you're on but you need to install make and probably some of the development tools

Comment: The OP's issue seems to be that something is specifying the wrong path: '/use' rather than '/usr'. So it's likely that make is already correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm using Mac (Catalina). I've downloaded make but it's at the path '/usr' instead of '/use' which as far as I can tell, does not exist